# How to display table result of counted rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
studentGradeTracker(
    student integer,
    courseID integer,
    sectionCompleted integer,
    grade integer);
```

`grade` is an integer 4-0 where 4 will be an 'A' and 0 will be an 'F'.

The course is considered completed if the grade is 1 or higher.

I am trying to count the number of grades for each student and display them in the fashion

```
student | hoursCompleted
```

Is there a function like for each student count # of records where grade > 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT student, count(*) 
FROM studentGradeTracker 
WHERE Grade > 0 
GROUP BY student
```